# spark shuffle taking too long

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

here are my scenarios.

**scenario 1:**
 I have a dataframe with  5 columns selected(out of 1 TB total data), and after that there is a join with another data frame (6 GB), and then write to s3 , this process takes 25 mins.

**scenario 2:**
same as scenario 1 but added 5 more columns in the select (so total 10 columns selected), and everything same as scenario 1 , the process now takes more than 4 hours.Not sure why .

Any thoughts ?, I know the shuffle data is more now, but this bad ?, where should I look for clues ?

**Sample Code:**

```html
    val df1 = spark.read.parquet("s3://path1").select(5 cols)// (10 cols) 
    val filterIds=List("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8")
    val  df1_1=df1.filter(!col("tier1_id").isin(filterIds:_*))
    val df2 = spark.read.parquet("s3://path2").toDF("col1","col2").filter(col("col1").isNotNull)
    val df1_j_df2=df1_1.join(df2,df1_1.col("col1")===df2.col("col1"))
    df1_j_df2.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).parquet(config.getString("s3://path3")  + "data_dt=" + processDate + "/")
```

**explain plans from real code**

```html
/* select 5 columns */
== Physical Plan ==
*(5) SortMergeJoin [mdn_ssp_raw#95], [mdn#111], Inner
:- *(2) Sort [mdn_ssp_raw#95 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(mdn_ssp_raw#95, 4000)
:     +- *(1) Project [mdn#13 AS mdn_ssp_raw#95, url#14, application#20, tier1_id#15, tier2_id#16, CASE WHEN (isnull(cast(hits#24 as int)) || (length(trim(cast(cast(hits#24 as int) as string), None)) = 0)) THEN -1 ELSE cast(hits#24 as int) END AS hits#73, CASE WHEN (isnull(cast(bytes_down#26 as int)) || (length(trim(cast(cast(bytes_down#26 as int) as string), None)) = 0)) THEN -1 ELSE cast(bytes_down#26 as int) END AS bytes_down#84, cast(bytes_up#25 as int) AS bytes_up#62, service_provider_id#17, timestamp#12]
:        +- *(1) Filter (((tier1_id#15 INSET (1195)) && NOT tier1_id#15 IN (1002,1003,1184,1185,1188,1063,1064,1065)) && isnotnull(mdn#13))
:           +- *(1) FileScan parquet [timestamp#12,mdn#13,url#14,tier1_id#15,tier2_id#16,service_provider_id#17,application#20,hits#24,bytes_up#25,bytes_down#26] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://path1/processing/browsing/ssp/ssp_nation_aggregat..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [In(tier1_id, [1195,1193,1003,1098,1055,1048,1146,1167,1040,1020,1079,1017,1136,1154,1115,1050,11..., ReadSchema: struct<timestamp:string,mdn:string,url:string,tier1_id:string,tier2_id:string,service_provider...
+- *(4) Sort [mdn#111 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(mdn#111, 4000)
      +- *(3) Project [_COL_0#106 AS MACDEVID#110, _COL_1#107 AS mdn#111]
         +- *(3) Filter isnotnull(_COL_1#107)
            +- *(3) FileScan parquet [_COL_0#106,_COL_1#107] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://path2/poc3/id_op_device_mdn_ssp], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(_COL_1)], ReadSchema: struct<_COL_0:string,_COL_1:string>


/* select 10 columns*/

== Physical Plan ==
*(5) SortMergeJoin [mdn_ssp_raw#110], [mdn#131], Inner
:- *(2) Sort [mdn_ssp_raw#110 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
:  +- Exchange hashpartitioning(mdn_ssp_raw#110, 4000)
:     +- *(1) Project [mdn#13 AS mdn_ssp_raw#110, url#14, application#20, tier1_id#15, tier2_id#16, CASE WHEN (isnull(cast(hits#24 as int)) || (length(trim(cast(cast(hits#24 as int) as string), None)) = 0)) THEN -1 ELSE cast(hits#24 as int) END AS hits#78, CASE WHEN (isnull(cast(bytes_down#26 as int)) || (length(trim(cast(cast(bytes_down#26 as int) as string), None)) = 0)) THEN -1 ELSE cast(bytes_down#26 as int) END AS bytes_down#94, cast(bytes_up#25 as int) AS bytes_up#62, service_provider_id#17, timestamp#12, device_id#18, os_id#19, ntc_id#32, ad_id#33, session_id#31]
:        +- *(1) Filter (((tier1_id#15 INSET (1195)) && NOT tier1_id#15 IN (1002,1003,1184,1185,1188,1063,1064,1065)) && isnotnull(mdn#13))
:           +- *(1) FileScan parquet [timestamp#12,mdn#13,url#14,tier1_id#15,tier2_id#16,service_provider_id#17,device_id#18,os_id#19,application#20,hits#24,bytes_up#25,bytes_down#26,session_id#31,ntc_id#32,ad_id#33] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://path1/processing/browsing/ssp/ssp_nation_aggregat..., PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [In(tier1_id, [1195,1193,1003,1098,1055,1048,1146,1167,1040,1020,1079,1017,1136,1154,1115,1050,11..., ReadSchema: struct<timestamp:string,mdn:string,url:string,tier1_id:string,tier2_id:string,service_provider...
+- *(4) Sort [mdn#131 ASC NULLS FIRST], false, 0
   +- Exchange hashpartitioning(mdn#131, 4000)
      +- *(3) Project [_COL_0#126 AS MACDEVID#130, _COL_1#127 AS mdn#131]
         +- *(3) Filter isnotnull(_COL_1#127)
            +- *(3) FileScan parquet [_COL_0#126,_COL_1#127] Batched: true, Format: Parquet, Location: InMemoryFileIndex[s3://path2/poc3/id_op_device_mdn_ssp], PartitionFilters: [], PushedFilters: [IsNotNull(_COL_1)], ReadSchema: struct<_COL_0:string,_COL_1:string>
```

**Spark Submit**

```html
 --conf spark.sql.parquet.fs.optimized.committer.optimization-enabled=true 
 --executor-memory 28g 
 --executor-cores 5 
 --driver-memory 28g  
 --driver-cores 5  
 --conf spark.executor.memoryOverhead=2800  
 --conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=30" 
 --conf "spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=300" 
 --conf "spark.shuffle.compress=true"   
 --conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=4000   
 --conf spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer 
 --conf spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema=true 
 --conf spark.sql.parquet.filterPushdown=true 
 --conf spark.sql.parquet.compression.codec=gzip 
 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true 
 --conf spark.sql.hive.metastorePartitionPruning=true 
 --conf spark.speculation=true 
 --conf "spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true" 
 --conf "spark.shuffle.spill.compress=true"  
 --conf spark.default.parallelism=1000  
 --conf spark.memory.storageFraction=0.1
```

**The slowest part:**

[image: events time line]

[image: DAG Visualization]

[image: stats]

Comment: Maybe you can share `explain`s for both cases? It will be more useful than a simplistic code sample.

Comment: Please provide your real code. This sample code is perfect and shouldn't take un-proportionate time

Comment: What are the types of the columns? What are the sizes of your output results for the two scenarios?

Comment: all the 5 new columns added are Strings, and I had to kill the second scenario run, as its taking more than 3 hrs, and I have a cut off at 3 hrs, as this process wont save any money compared to the existing process.The size of scenario  1 is 30% lesser than the input which is approx 1 TB.

Comment: There’s no difference in the execution plan . Most likely some of the new columns are too big

Comment: One possible explanation could be that adding more columns forces shuffle to spill to disk. Can you check it in Spark UI?

Comment: Yes , it is spilling to disk, should I increase executor memory ?

Comment: Its either that, or increasing the number of executors... How many executors are there now, and what are their memory settings?

Comment: @mazaneicha added spark submit command in the original post, as its too long to post here.

Comment: Since total executor memory is already close to 32GB (28g + 2.8g), I'd start by reducing the `--executor-cores` to 2-3 and increasing `maxExecutors`. Also curious, how did you come up with `spark.memory.storageFraction=0.1`?

Comment: thanks @mazaneicha, will try it out,  I had spark.memory.storageFraction=0.1 as I was trying to give less space for caching purpose as I am not doing any, and give all the jvm heap to any of spark internals, OOM etc.Please feel free to correct it.

Comment: @mazaneicha, it did not work, tried  3 cores, and still it was dying to finish.

Comment: Did you increase the number of executors? Were they all spilling uniformly, or just some of them (which would indicate a data skew)? If dataset in scenario #2 still can't fit into memory, an ugly solution could be to try splitting it down the middle ( `...where col1 <= X...` / `...where col1 > X...` ) and run two joins sequentially. Should still be faster than one huge join...

Comment: I did increase executors,I have added the task details that is super slow, please see if there is something you can spot, there is lot of orange , which is shuffle read time.I probably  can not do the split, as the column has random values every day.